# OpenGL skeletal animation performance

Tags: c++, optimization, opengl, skinning

I'm in a bit of a situation.

You see, when rendering my model with my renderMesh() function, the game was at about 30fps. When rendering to a display list, and running that, the fps went to about 450fps. Thats a gain of 1500%. I was overjoyed by this, for it meant that OpenGL wasn't the cause of the lag, it was the function, and that can be optimized.

But now I want to render a skinned mesh, so I will need to update the vertex positions per frame, but nothing else. So it would be a waste of time running renderMesh() because the overhead of patching together all the faces, ect... is unnecessary. I want to cache this data, but display lists won't work because of the volatile vertex coords.

What would be the best solution (other than to optimize my renderMesh(), which I will be doing anyway).

Comment: It's a bit difficult to suggest improvements when we see no actual code. If you're doing simple skinning, you could even write a GLSL shader for it to do the work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [VBOs](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html) and get improvement. Should be same or better then lists. 1500% improvement is strange. Are you sure you measuring FPS right?

Comment: Yes, I am measuring based on CPU ticks, nothing more accurate.

Answer (score 5):

I can only suggest:

1. Using fewer vertices
2. Moving your vertices (or most of them) in rigid groups --- that way each group can be a list
3. [Vertex Buffer Objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object)